# Place multiple JPanels on top of each other

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I have this code, and it makes a JPanel and adds it to a JScrollPanel. It works fine, but when I try to add a second JPanel it removes the first one and adds the second one. I would like to be able to place JPanels on top of JPanels, how can I do that?

```
// Location of an image:
String file = wfc.getSelectedFile().getPath();

// Creates images from different types:
ImageHandler image = new ImageHandler();
BufferedImage imageData = image.imageData(file);

// Extends JPanel, Layer is a JPanel
Layer layer = new Layer(image.width(), image.height());
layer.setImage(imageData);
layer.setSizeFromLoaded();
// A list of all the JPanels added
Layers.set(Layers.layers.size(), layer);

// Adds a JPanel to the JScrollPanel
imagePane.getViewport().add(layer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Here is the full method, it opens a file browser, then when the image is selected it runs the above code

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    WebFileChooser wfc = null;
    if(wfc == null){
        wfc = new WebFileChooser(this, "Open an Image");
        wfc.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        wfc.setAvailableFilter(GlobalConstants.IMAGES_AND_FOLDERS_FILTER);
        wfc.setChooseFilter(GlobalConstants.IMAGES_FILTER);
        wfc.setCurrentDirectory("/Users");
    }
    wfc.setVisible(true);

    if(wfc.getResult() == StyleConstants.OK_OPTION){
        String file = wfc.getSelectedFile().getPath();

        ImageHandler image = new ImageHandler();
        BufferedImage imageData = image.imageData(file);

        Layer layer = new Layer(image.width(), image.height());
        layer.setImage(imageData);
        layer.setSizeFromLoaded();
        Layers.set(Layers.layers.size(), layer);

        imagePane.getViewport().add(layer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a JLayeredPane. But be careful, you might have to `setOpaque(false)`

Comment: perfect! When I add, can I place it on top of the old pane instead of behind it?

Comment: Yes, just use JLayeredPane.add(Component, int) where the int is the layer number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Zove Games suggestion and placed it within a JLayerdPanel, and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

You may wish to consider placing you panels into a single master panel which is using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

This will allow you to easily switch between panels giving the illusion of layered panels without the hassle of doing it manually.

Something like...

```
JPanel master = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
master.add(new ChildPane()); // Or what ever child you want to add
master.add(new ChildPane()); // Or what ever child you want to add
//...
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(master);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put both of the panels inside of one JPanel, and then put that in the JScrollPane.